# Conditional probability finding another given probability

Tags: probability

If I have $P(A) = 0.05$ and $P(B \mid A) = 0.95$,

the first question asks

1) What is the $P(A \cap B)$?

I did: $P(A \cap B) = P(B \mid A) \cdot P(A)$ and $0.95 \cdot 0.05 = 0.0475$.

Then it asks:

2) $P(B' \mid A) =\ ?$

I tried doing: $1- P(B \mid A)$ and got $0.05$ but I don't feel like this is right. What do I need to do to find $P(B' \mid A)$?

Answer (score 0):

You are right!

Another way that you could see it:

$$
P(\text{not }B\mid A)=\frac{P(A\text{ and not }B)}{P(A)}.
$$
But 
$$
P(A\text{ and not }B)+P(A\text{ and } B)=P(A),
$$
which rearranges as
$$
P(A\text{ and not }B)=P(A)-P(A\text{ and }B),
$$
to give
$$
P(\text{not }B\mid A)=\frac{P(A)-P(A\text{ and }B)}{P(A)}=1-\frac{P(A\text{ and }B)}{P(A)}=1-P(B\mid A).
$$